# Let's play ASCII mini-golf

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, path-finding, simulation

Let's play code golf... by playing golf.

### Input

Your input will be a string consisting of `#`'s, an `o`, an `@`, and `.`'s. For example:

```
......@..
.....##..
.........
......o..
```

`.` - playable golf course (all shots must end on one of these)
`#` - a barrier (shots cannot go through this)
`o` - the starting position of your golf ball
`@` - the hole

### How to Play ASCII Golf

You start at the `o`. Here is a valid shot from point `A` to point `B`:

1) This shot is straight line that can be drawn between `A` and `B` (no curved shots).

```
A....
....B
```

2) The line `AB` may not intersect with a `#` (barrier), e.g.:

```
A.#.B
```

It **may**, however, be tangent to a barrier:

```
A#
.B
```

3) *(For clarity)* You may **not** bounce shots off barriers or the edge of the golf course.

### Output

Print to `stdout` (or an acceptable equivalent) the minimum number of shots to get the ball into the hole `@`. If it is not possible, print `-1`.

### Examples

```
o....@
```

`=> 1`

```
o.#.@
```

`=> -1`

```
o..#
..#@
```

`=> 2` (you can pass through the vertices of a `#`, but not the edges)

```
o#...#
.#.#.#
...#.@
```

`=> 4`

Comment: Can’t your “6” example be done in 4 shots (south 1, southeast 1, northeast 2, southeast 2)?

Comment: In the worst case you would need to write/golf a pathfinder algorithm like A* or something similar. Which may be quite difficult/challenging for some languages.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Good point, fixed.

Comment: What would `..@ \no#.` mean?

Comment: Can you do this in 1 shot? `o###` / `#..#` / `###@` (3 rows)

Comment: i think that op must define which particular cases make a ball rebouncing off an egde.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg why can it not be 3 ? south 2, n-e 3, etc ..

Comment: @aditsu No, because the line would intersect the edge of a `#`.

Comment: @Agawa001 The question is clear: “You may not bounce shots off barriers or the edge of the golf course.” And no, there’s no 3 shot solution.

Comment: What about this: `o.##` / `##.@` ? 1 shot?

Comment: @aditsu. Yes, because the line from `o` to `@` only intersects the vertices of the `#`'s

Comment: What? On hold? I'm pretty clear about the challenge now, but it took a couple of comments to make sure. @AMACB you should probably explain the exact trajectory of the ball and shape of the barriers more clearly. If not, maybe I can edit the question later.

Comment: I don't have time right now, but I will try to get to it soon.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 469

Pretty long, but it's a start:

```python
R=range
def l(c,x,y,z,t):
 f=abs(z-x);g=1-2*(z<x);p=abs(t-y);q=1-2*(t<y);v=r=0
 for i in R(f):
  w=f+(2*i+1)*p
  for j in R(v,(w-1)/2/f+1):r|='.'>c[x+g*i][y+q*j]
  v=w/2/f
 for j in R(v,p+1):r|='.'>c[z][y+q*j]
 return r
def f(c):
 a="".join(c);n=len(c[0]);b=len(a);d=[[9**9*l(c,i/n,i%n,j/n,j%n)+1for i in R(b)]for j in R(b)]
 for k in R(b):
  for i in R(b):
   for j in R(b):
    t=d[i][j]=min(d[i][j],d[i][k]+d[k][j])
    if"o@"==a[i]+a[j]:r=t
 return-1if r>9**9else r
```

Function f takes a list of strings and returns the number of shots.

Test suite:

```python
def test(s,r):
 print"ok"if f(s.split())==r else"fail"

test("o # @", -1)
test("......@.. .....##.. ......... ......o..", 2)
test("o....@", 1)
test("o.#.@", -1)
test("o..# ..#@", 2)
test("o#...# .#.#.# ...#.@", 4)
test("o### #..# ###@", 3)
test("o.## ##.@", 1)
test("...o .@#.", 2)
```